# how to connecting to sqlite by qt and run it on android

Tags: android, database, qt, sqlite, connection

I want to connect sqlite database and write an Android app.
but,when i run the app i give an error which said: database not open.

```
#include "csqlconnect.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>

CSqlConnect::CSqlConnect()
{
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE","MyConnection" );
QFile dfile("./myfile.sqlite");
bool dbf=dfile.exists();
if (!dbf)
{
QFile::copy("assets:/myfile.sqlite", "./myfile.sqlite");
QFile::setPermissions("./myfile.sqlite",QFile::WriteOwner |    QFile::ReadOwner);
}
db.setDatabaseName( "myfile.sqlite" );
bool open=db.open();
if(!open)
{
QMessageBox::warning(0, "Failed to connect!", "Error connecting to     database: "+db.lastError().driverText());
   // qDebug()<<"Failed!!!!";
}

if(open)
{
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("create table person "
      "(id integer primary key, "
      "firstname varchar(20), "
      "lastname varchar(30), "
      "age integer)");
```

}

```
 QSqlQuery query2;
```

query2.prepare("INSERT INTO person    (id,firstname,lastname,age)VALUES(:ID,:FIRSTNAME,:LASTNAME,:AGE)");
     query2.bindValue(":ID",1);
     query2.bindValue(":FIRSTNAME","ali");
     query2.bindValue(":LASTNAME","alavi");
     query2.bindValue(":AGE",24);
     query2.exec();
     QSqlTableModel model;
      model.setTable("person");
     model.select();
      QSqlRecord  record=model.record(0);
     result=record.value("firstname").toString();
     }

```
QString CSqlConnect::getValue()
{
   return result;
}

CSqlConnect::~CSqlConnect()
{
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to create the SQLite file in the current working directory (`./myfile.sqlite`), which is most probably not writable from the app, on Android.

Better get a writable path from [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) explicitly:

```
const auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);

errno = 0;
if (!QDir(path).mkpath()) {
    // return error, get details from strerror(errno)
    …
    return;
}

db.setDatabaseName(path + QStringLiteral("/myfile.sqlite"));
if (!db.open()) {
   // handle error
   …
   return;
}

…
```

Comment: It's surprising how hard this answer is to find in google. Wasted 2 hours before coming here. To others that come here filled with rage and frustration: now just use `#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID` and you're there.